# Reactor Flux subscriber stream stopped when using reduce on flatMap

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want change my code for single subscriber. Now i have

```
auctionFlux.window(Duration.ofSeconds(120), Duration.ofSeconds(120)).subscribe(
        s -> s.groupBy(Auction::getItem).subscribe( longAuctionGroupedFlux -> longAuctionGroupedFlux.reduce(new ItemDumpStats(), this::calculateStats )
));
```

This code is working correctly reduce method is very simple. I tried change my code for single subscriber

```
    auctionFlux.window(Duration.ofSeconds(120), Duration.ofSeconds(120))
        .flatMap(window -> window.groupBy(Auction::getItem))
        .flatMap(longAuctionGroupedFlux -> longAuctionGroupedFlux.reduce(new ItemDumpStats(), this::calculateStats))
        .subscribe(itemDumpStatsMono -> log.info(itemDumpStatsMono.toString()));
```

This is my code, and this code is not working. No errors and no results. After debugging i found code is stuck on second flatMap when i reducing stream. I think problem is on flatMap merging, stucking on Mono resolve. Some one now how to fix this problem and use only single subscriber?

How to replicate, you can use another class or create one. In small size is working but on bigger is dying

```
List<Auction> auctionList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0;i<100000;i++){
    Auction a = new Auction((long) i, "test");
    a.setItem((long) (i%50));
    auctionList.add(a);
}

Flux.fromIterable(auctionList).groupBy(Auction::getId).flatMap(longAuctionGroupedFlux ->
        longAuctionGroupedFlux.reduce(new ItemDumpStats(), (itemDumpStats, auction) -> itemDumpStats)).collectList().subscribe(itemDumpStats -> System.out.println(itemDumpStats.toString()));
```

On this approach is instant result but I using 3 subscribers

```
Flux.fromIterable(auctionList)
        .groupBy(Auction::getId)
        .subscribe(
                auctionIdAuctionGroupedFlux -> auctionIdAuctionGroupedFlux.reduce(new ItemDumpStats(), (itemDumpStats, auction) -> itemDumpStats).subscribe(itemDumpStats -> System.out.println(itemDumpStats.toString()
                )
        ));
```

Comment: You're not providing enough details here, we can't help when most of the code is missing. Please take a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @BrianClozel what code you need? I can add reduce method and 2 classes Auction and ItemDumpStats.
When i was debugging it was entered inside calculateStats method and calculating what i need, i think problem is when he resolve Mono into Flux. Reduce is returning `Mono<ItemDumpStats>` but flatMap is changing this into `Flux<ItemDumpStats>`, this is taking infinite time in stream, and subscribe is never done.

Comment: I added code for replicate @BrianClozel, it`s look like size of flux is problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the behavior you described is related to the interaction between `groupBy` chained with `flatMap`. 
Check [groupBy](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-) documentation. It states that:

> The groups need to be drained and consumed downstream for groupBy to work correctly. Notably when the criteria produces a large amount of groups, it can lead to hanging if the groups are not suitably consumed downstream (eg. due to a flatMap with a maxConcurrency parameter that is set too low).

By default, `maxConcurrency (flatMap)` is set to 256 (i checked the source code of 3.2.2). So, 
selecting more than 256 groups may cause the execution to hang (particularly when all execution happens on the same thread).

The following code helps in understanding what happens when you chain the operators groupBy and flatMap:

```
@Test
public void groupAndFlatmapTest() {
    val groupCount = 257;
    val groupSize = 513;
    val list = rangeClosed(1, groupSize * groupCount).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    val source = Flux.fromIterable(list)
            .groupBy(i -> i % groupCount)
            .flatMap(Flux::collectList);
    StepVerifier.create(source).expectNextCount(groupCount).expectComplete().verify();
}
```

The execution of this code hangs. Changing `groupCount` to 256 or less makes the test pass (for every value of `groupSize`).

So, regarding your original problem, it is very possible that you are creating a large amount of groups with your key-selector `Auction::getItem`.

Comment: Thx, describe where is problem. Parallel is helping right now, i think i have more that 10k groups.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `parallel` fixed problem, but i looking answer why reduce dramatically slow flatMap.